# Content Parsing Error with Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am receiving the following error when attempting to analyze a PDF file that is an architectural drawing:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "2018",
        "innerError": {
            "requestId": "7ffbbd94-fab5-4200-b32c-990d6029a1cc"
        },
        "message": "Content parsing error."
    }
}
```

I am using the Form Recognizer API, and the PDF file has both text and drawing symbols on it. I have also tried different content types in the Header ("multipart/form-data", "application/pdf") with the same results. If I screenshot the PDF file (it's one page) and save it as an image it processes successfully.

Does Form Recognizer support these types of PDF files? I am wondering if I am missing something or that architectural drawings are not currently supported.

EDIT: I have attached a couple of example drawing files that I am working with (obfuscating identifying information). The Material Legends file is the main file I need to extract information out of. For the Floor Plan file, I only want to extract the information on the Key Notes section.

Further clarification on the data I need to extract: I need to count instances of key terms/phrases that are detected. For example, I need to scan a file to see how many times it has the text 'Restroom' in it. I am okay with Form Recognizer putting what it sees in the Tokens section of the results.

**Material Legend Example**
[image: Material Legend]

**Floor Plan Example**
[image: Floor Plan]

Answer (score 0):

The Form Recognizer is focusing on Forms (purchase orders, tax forms) where there are text and values.  It would extract the key/value pair (address, name, ID) from the documents.  What type of info do you want to get out of an architecture drawing? 
if you could show a typical architecture drawing (a similar drawing in public domain without private info), and your expected result,  form recognizer team could look into this.

hope this helps. 
thanks
-xin-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Consider training a model with [OCR Form Tools](https://github.com/microsoft/OCR-Form-Tools) or [FOTT website](https://fott.azurewebsites.net/)
From the OCR Form Tools github site: "To go thru a complete label-train-analyze scenario, you need a set of at least six forms of the same type. You will label five forms to train a model and one form to test the model."

The model provides a bit of scene analysis support to focus extraction from form and json mapping.

If you have not already done so, try testing via their [Form Recognizer API v2](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomModel)